# Does XOrg have a notion of system-wide default font?

Tags: fonts, xorg, freebsd, default-settings, gtk

How and where can I change the default system font? For now it appears to be DejaVu 11, which looks horrible on my laptop.

I mean the font that is used in menus or labels. For example when I open Firefox for the first time or any KDE application for the first time (Konsole, Okular, etc) all menus and labels are drawn using DejaVu 11. Chromium appears to be using its own font. The font used for menus and label doesn't appear to be changeable from the application itself so I guess there must be some system-wide setting. Does it depend on the window manager? I am using Lumina at this moment.

It could be related to GTK or similar UI framework, do they have system-wide font configuration files?

Comment: Xorg does not have a default font. It's basically a graphics drawing and user I/O interface engine, nothing more. Window decoration is the task of the window manager, and menus is generally the task of the toolkit. This is illustrated by the fact that applications that use different toolkits use different fonts in the same place.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling this is good enough to be an answer.

Comment: In some cases it might have to do with fontconfig though, like which fonts are chosen to be matched for the typefaces name(sans, serif, monospace)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Yeah, I agree the first comment is good as an answer. As it turned out the default font is set separately for GTK and QT frameworks: https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/55323/#post-313330

Comment: I wrote it up as a comment because I didn't have the time to write an actual answer then and there. I'll see a little later if I can write an actual answer around that comment, if nobody beats me to it.